# ValueError: X has 231 features per sample; expecting 1228

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Here is the top of the script where the model was trained (I am using Logistic Regression):

```
data_raw = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)

pd.Series(data_raw.columns) 
pd.Series(data_raw.dtypes)

data_raw.describe(include='all')

data_raw['collision_type'] = data_raw.loc[0:, 'collision_type'].replace('?', 'Unknown')

data_raw['property_damage'] = data_raw.loc[0:, 'property_damage'].replace('?', 'Unknown')

data_raw.isnull().sum()

dropping_columns = ['months_as_customer', 'policy_bind_date', 'age', 'policy_number', 'policy_annual_premium', 'insured_zip', 
                    'capital_gains', 'capital_loss', 'total_claim_amount', 'injury_claim', 'property_claim', 'vehicle_claim',
                   'auto_year']

data_cleaned = data_raw.drop(dropping_columns, axis=1)

data_preprocessed = pd.get_dummies(data_cleaned, drop_first=True)


targets = data_preprocessed['fraud_reported_Y']
features = data_preprocessed.drop(['fraud_reported_Y'], axis=1)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, targets, test_size=0.2, random_state=420)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = logreg.predict(x_test)
```

Now I'm trying to make predictions on a test input (test dataset imported from SQL table):

```
test = df['TestTable']
test = test[0]
sql = 'SELECT * FROM '+ test
test_raw = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)

#sample_rows = test_raw.sample(n=5)

test_raw.describe(include='all')

test_raw['collision_type'] = data_raw.loc[0:, 'collision_type'].replace('?', 'Unknown')

test_raw['property_damage'] = data_raw.loc[0:, 'property_damage'].replace('?', 'Unknown')

test_raw.isnull().sum()

print(test_raw.shape)

test_dropped = test_raw.drop(dropping_columns, axis=1)
test_preprocessed = pd.get_dummies(test_dropped, drop_first=True)

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)
test_predicted = logreg.predict(test_preprocessed)
```

Here is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-149-e6d470e94433>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/BusinessUser/Downloads/insurance_claim_fraud_detection-master/insurance_claim_fraud_detection.py', wdir='C:/Users/BusinessUser/Downloads/insurance_claim_fraud_detection-master')

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/BusinessUser/Downloads/insurance_claim_fraud_detection-master/insurance_claim_fraud_detection.py", line 402, in <module>
    test_predicted = logreg.predict(test_preprocessed)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 289, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 270, in decision_function
    % (X.shape[1], n_features))

ValueError: X has 231 features per sample; expecting 1228
```

My train dataset has 999 rows with a final prediction result column while the test dataset has 50 rows without prediction result column. The other columns are basically the same.

I'm quite a newbie and I'm pretty sure there is such basic thing I have not known about this model training. Thank you guys so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the number of columns (features) of the data you use for prediction (`test_preprocessed`)  is the same as for the data used for training/test (`x_train`, `x_test`) using the function `shape` for instance or `len(test_preprocessed.columns)`.

Comment: Hi @user2314737, thank you for your help! As I called the pd.get_dummies() I would say the number of columns in my test input is less than the number of columns in my original training dataset, since I have less records/rows in my test input. Does the number of features/columns have to be exactly the same for both training set and test input?

Comment: Yes @anhnguyen the trained model is basically a function that takes n-dimensional input and gives as output some other value, where n is the number of features

Comment: Hi @user2314737 thanks for the helpful response. So is there a way to ensure the number of features matching from training dataset and testing input? I'm expecting the testing input would have less records than the training data, so after converting the categorical values to dummy values would it result in less number of features? Please correct me if my knowledge is wrong.